# Match and highlight urls

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I'm trying to make it so urls are highlighted and a shortcut can be used when the cursor is on top of one to open it in browser. Added this to a syntax file:

```
syn match matchURL '/http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*/'
hi matchURL ctermfg=14
```

Tested with `https://www.archlinux.org` but it didn't get highlighted. (Ofc I tested simpler syn matches and highlights to ensure that syntax highlighting is working, so I conclude the regex is probably wrong?). How to make highlight urls then?

Also once urls are highlighted, is there a simple way to copy to a register/variable the text that is highlighted under the cursor?

Comment: remove either `'` or `/` from start and end of regexp

Comment: use `matchadd()` family of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra quotes in your regex, it should look like:

```
syn match matchURL /http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*/
hi matchURL ctermfg=14
```

Then, to save the match under the cursor in a variable, you can do:

```
let link = expand('<cWORD>')
let link = matchstr(link, 'http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*')
```

Comment: `syn match matchURL /http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*/` not working, should be only `match matchURL /http[s]\?:\/\/[[:alnum:]%\/_#.-]*/`, it worked liked this for me.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight URL, you can use [vim-highlighturl](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-highlighturl), which can highlight all kinds of URLs.

To open URL in browser, you can use [open-browser.vim](https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim) and define the following shortcut to open URL in browser:

```
nmap ob <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
vmap ob <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
```